# Shell Script Random Cron job

Tags: shell, cron

I setup a cronjob to call myscript.sh every 5 min which then calls a php file between 30 sec and 3 in time and  I don't get it why the average Interval is 05:09.

I want to call cron2_.php every 4-8 min but no chance to achieve that.

Tank you.

Cron Job:  `*/5 * * * * myscript.sh`

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Grab a random value between 60-180 or ( between 30sec and 3 minutes )
value=$RANDOM
while [ $value -gt 180 ] || [ $value -lt 30 ] ; 
do
  value=$RANDOM
done

# Sleep for that time.
sleep $value

# Exectue Cron.
echo "Exectued on:$(date)" >> public_html/log_file.txt
exec php -f public_html/cron2_.php
```

Here is the exectuion time for 2 hours:
Average Interval -> 05:09

```
  Execution Time      Interval Min:Sec
    13:02:52            00:00
    13:07:06            04:14
    13:11:35            04:29
    13:17:34            05:59
    13:21:55            04:21
    13:26:54            04:59
    13:32:00            05:06
    13:35:50            03:50
    13:42:44            06:54
    13:47:03            04:19
    13:51:26            04:23
    13:56:48            05:22
    14:01:53            05:05
    14:07:42            05:49
    14:12:15            04:33
    14:16:22            04:07
    14:23:01            06:39
    14:27:17            04:16
    14:32:21            05:04
    14:35:57            03:36
    14:42:14            06:17
    14:45:44            03:30
    14:52:52            07:08
    14:56:50            03:58
    15:02:57            06:07
    15:06:43            03:46
    15:12:26            05:43
    15:16:29            04:03
    15:22:00            05:31
    15:25:35            03:35
    15:31:51            06:16
    15:37:51            06:00
    15:42:56            05:05
    15:47:32            04:36
    15:50:36            03:04
    15:55:45            05:09
    16:02:15            06:30
    16:06:10            03:55
    16:11:11            05:01
    16:15:56            04:45
    16:21:58            06:02
    16:25:56            03:58
    16:31:09            05:13
    16:37:06            05:57
    16:42:30            05:24
    16:45:36            03:06
```

Comment: How did you get 79 for the "seconds" position of your average time?

Comment: Measure how many seconds it takes for `$RANDOM` to produce a number in your range? I would not be surprised if it takes dozens of seconds.

Comment: KevinChen should be 5:09 fixed it.
@tripleee I tried that and it takes from 2-3 sec max to get a number in that range. Can it be the php script execution taking alot of time ?

Comment: If you start a cronjob every 5 minutes, as per the question as currently written, you will, over a long enough period of time, get an average of one execution every 5 minutes regardless of what random delay is included in the script.

Comment: @John1024 Ok I understand the average time of 5 min, but why do I get intervals of 3 min that's confusing?

Comment: @JetonRamadani Say one script starts at 15 minutes after the hour and has a long delay,say 3 min.  It executes at 18 minutes after. Suppose the next  script (starting 20 minutes after) has a short delay (30 seconds) so it executes at 20:30 after the hour.  Then, the interval between them is 20:30 - 18 = 2 minutes 30 seconds.

Comment: Thank you man! Up-voted your comment. Should i replace the while loop with a simple `$((RANDOM%180+60))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want your script to run every 4 to 8 minutes.  Let's say then that we want, on average, one execution every 6 minutes.  In that case, set the crontab line to:

```
*/6 * * * * myscript.sh
```

Next, in your script, put a random delay of zero to two minutes:

```
sleep $(($RANDOM % 120))
```

Consider two extreme cases.  First, suppose that one job waits the maximum 2 minutes and the next waits the minimum of 0 minutes.  The time between their executions is 4 minutes.  For the second case, consider the opposite: the first job waits the minimum of 0 minutes and the second waits the maximum of 2 minutes.  In this case, the time between their executions is 8 minutes.  Thus, this approach achieves a wait of 4 to 8 minutes with an average wait of 6 minutes.

Comment: Amazing, I was just reading about modulo operation and you answered. I will go with your solution @John1024